# Conversion pixel warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

I have a conversion pixels script that has produced a php warning on my website. My code is below:

```
foreach ($result as $myrow =>$pixelcode) {
    $pixelcode = $myrow['pixel'];
    //echo $pixelcode;
    //echo $row['pixel']
    echo $pixelcode;
}
```

And here is the message:

> **Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

My code hasn't changed. Any ideas on how to fix this warning?

Comment: The `$result` may be `empty` or not an `array`. Check those..

Comment: `$result` is not an array. `var_dump($result)` to see WHAT it is.

Comment: The line $pixelcode = $myrow['pixel'] is at odds with your foreach which is splitting apart each of your array keys into myrow and values into pixelcode, you can learn more: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: You can't have an array as key, so that `$myrow['pixel'];` part shouldn't work, even after you fix the _invalid argument_ warning.

Comment: @katie Any ideas on keeping it as an array?

Comment: @chronotrigga - I think you need to better understand the structure of $result to complete the code, right now the code doesn't make sense as is, you are setting $pixelcode in both the foreach and the first statement, which isn't correct, add var_dump($result) before the foreach as Mark B suggested, you will be able to then write the code to pick it apart correctly